# How do I set up Allure with JUnit in an IntelliJ project?

Tags: allure

I've been reading in the [Allure wiki](https://github.com/allure-framework/allure-core/wiki) however I do not seem to be able to get started with Allure.

I have an IntelliJ project which I use to run JUnit tests with Selenium. I want to add Allure for better feedback after test runs. However I've not been able to understand how Allure would integrate with the rest of my project.

On [the wiki page for JUnit](https://github.com/allure-framework/allure-core/wiki/JUnit) it looks like Allure with JUnit only supports maven projects? How can I set up allure to work with an IntelliJ project?

Answer (score 4):

> I want to add Allure for better feedback after test runs

It is strange that you don't have a build tool. 
But for single test (as you mention) following will work.

1. Dependencies - you need aither allure-junit-adaptor or allure-testng-adaptor
2. Allure implements test listener, which should be added to test runner:

   - For TestNG it happens automatically (once you add adaptor dependency).
   - For JUnit you should add listener manually. I don't know how to add it to Intellij Idea JUnit runner, but you can always run tests programmatically:

   public static void main(String[] args) {
       JUnitCore runner = new JUnitCore();
       runner.addListener(new AllureRunListener());
       runner.run(CalculatorTest.class);
   }

That will generate XML report in target/allure-results folder.

3. If you need advanced Allure features like file attachments and test steps you need another dependency (aspectjweaver) and according JVM args, e.g.

   -javaagent:lib/aspectjweaver-1.8.7.jar
4. To generate HTML report from existing XML report you can:

   - either use Allure CLI (requires tool installation http://wiki.qatools.ru/display/AL/Allure+Commandline)
   - or use 'mvn site' on existing project (e.g. https://github.com/allure-examples/allure-junit-example)
5. Open your HTML report in Firefox (or look [here](https://github.com/allure-framework/allure-core/wiki/FAQ-and-Troubleshooting#i-see-nothing-when-opening-the-report-page-in-my-browser--access-denied-message) how to open locally generated report in Chrome).

Comment: public static void main(String[] args) { JUnitCore runner = new JUnitCore(); runner.addListener(new AllureRunListener()); runner.run(CalculatorTest.class); } This is deprecated in 1.6.2. How it should be done with the new version? I can't figure it out by the link from  the AllureRunListener class which points to github...

Answer (score 0):

To have allure-results after launching JUnit4 tests from IDE using context menu or controls on the gutter I use @RunWith anntotation where I set my custom runner with AllureJUnit4 listener.

CustomRunner class

```
package ru.atconsulting.qa.system.junit4runners;

import io.qameta.allure.junit4.AllureJunit4;
import org.junit.runner.notification.RunNotifier;
import org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner;
import org.junit.runners.model.InitializationError;

public class CustomRunner extends BlockJUnit4ClassRunner {
    /**
     * Creates a BlockJUnit4ClassRunner to run {@code klass}
     *
     * @param klass
     * @throws InitializationError if the test class is malformed.
     */
    public CustomRunner(Class<?> klass) throws InitializationError {
        super(klass);
    }

    @Override
    public void run(RunNotifier notifier) {
        notifier.addListener(new AllureJunit4()); //just add listener
        super.run(notifier);
    }
}
```

Using @RunWith annotation in test classes

```
@RunWith(CustomRunner.class)
public class ExampleSuite {

    @Test
    public void testExample() {
    ....
    }

}
```